# Kovacic's algorithm

Tags: differential-equations

Kovacic’s algorithm is used to find out whether or not an ODE has a Liouvillian solution, and if it has, then what that solution is. My question is: Is there any code written in *Mathematica* for Kovacic's algorithm?

Comment: Well, the documentation says that `DSolve[]` is partly based on the Kovacic algorithm...

Comment: See [Linear Second-Order ODEs with Rational Coefficients](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveLinearSecondOrderODEsWithRationalCoefficients.html) and try Google with [mathematica Kovacic's algorithm](https://www.google.ch/search?q=mathematica+for+Kovacic%27s+algorithm&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Z3TFVtWWDsTkaK31rvAN#q=mathematica+Kovacic%27s+algorithm)